# Programmatically adding images from a URL to WP then adding to repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to programmatically add images from a URL to the Wordpress media library (that part works) and then adding each image to a repeater row of [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/).

At the moment it's only adding the last image to the first row. There should be 5 images (therefore 5 rows in the repeater) but the repeater only contains one row with the last image.

Where am I going wrong?

When outputting `$item` within the loop it's correctly outputting 5 image ID's so the problem seems to be the update part where it's just overwriting the first row... I put a `break;` in after the first loop and it showed the first image.

```
// Product Carousel Images
$fullpath = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/import/";
foreach($html->find('div[id=imageTabContent] img[class=img-responsive]') as $element) {

  $strippedpath = strstr($element->src, 'images');
  $url = $fullpath . $strippedpath;
  $image = media_sideload_image($url, $post_id, $strippedtitle, $return = 'id');

  $images[] = $image;

}
$counter = 1;
foreach($images as $item) {
  echo $item;
  echo "<br />";
  $field_key = "field_5ae05c498ac63";
  $value = array(
    array(
      "image"   => $item,
    )
  );
  update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
  $counter++;
}
```

Comment: $field_key seems to be set to static value. It doesn't change inside the loop and update_field function updates same field 5 times.

Comment: @ElvinHaci The field key is the name of the repeater so that's meant to stay the same, it's supposed to be adding new rows to that repeater but doesn't.

Comment: I know. But your code would update same field 5 times. It doesn't get command to append second row, that's why it updates first value instead. I think you need to move update_field outside from loop and call it just one single time. Instead of that convert $value to array of 5 elements. Such as $value = array ( array('image'=>''), array ('image'=>''), .... );

Comment: @ElvinHaci I've followed their documentation here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/ (repeater example). But yeah that's an interesting idea... could you put it in an answer please?

Comment: sure, i will do it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would update same field 5 times.

It doesn't get command to append second row, that's why it updates first value instead. I think you need to move update_field outside from loop and call it just one single time. Instead of that convert $value to array of 5 elements. Such as

```
$value=array();
foreach($images as $item) {
  echo $item;
  echo "<br />";
  $field_key = "field_5ae05c498ac63";
  $value[]=array(
      "image" => $item,
    );
  $counter++;
}
update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
```

Comment: Great, thanks. It's very close, it's created the rows now but hasn't inputted the images.

Comment: Got it, I removed `$counter` next to the sub field and it worked! Thanks very much!!